# Define all subfolders as source folder

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Here's my build.gradle

```
    sourceSets {
    main {

        java.srcDirs = ['src/base', 'src/modules/module1', 'src/modules/module2', 'src/modules/module3']

        res.srcDirs = ['src/base/common-res', 'src/modules/com/features/module1/resources', 'src/modules/com/features/module2/resources', 'src/modules/com/features/module3/resources']
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Basically I want to have all the subfolders in "modules" folder to be sources folder, and all resources folder inside to be res folders.

In this way, but without defining every new folder:

[image]

I would like to have instead of module1, module2 etc a wildcard or whatever to indicate that all subfolders are source dirs.

How to do this?

Comment: if you have modules, shouldn't you be using different projects?

Comment: Does your app currently compile?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [GDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) to list the directories of a folder,
so you can try something like:

```
file("src/modules").eachDir { module ->
    file("src/modules/$module").eachDir {
        if (it == "resources" ) {
            java.srcDirs.add  "src/modules/$module/it"
        } else {
            res.srcDirs.add  "src/modules/$module/it"
        }
    }       
}
```

This will iterate over all directories in "src/modules" and then add every sub-directory of each module as source, except if it's called resources. Untested code, but should get you started.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, i've updated the question